# Show that $\textrm{trace}: \textrm{End}(V)\rightarrow k$ defined by $\textrm{trace}(\phi ):=\textrm{trace}(M(\phi ))$ is a linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

**The Problem**

Show that $\textrm{trace}: \textrm{End}(V)\rightarrow k$ defined by $\textrm{trace}(\phi ):=\textrm{trace}(M(\phi ))$ is a linear map.

---

**My Question**

I need some help with understanding the *notation* in this question.  In other words, I am having a difficult time "reading the question."  If anybody would be willing to dumb this down for me, I'd be incredibly grateful.  I think once I understand how to *start* this proof, I will be be fine.

I understand:

1. What $\textrm{trace}$ means.
2. What $\textrm{End}(V)$ means.
3. What a linear map is, and how to show that something is a linear map.

I do not understand:

1. What $\phi$ means in this context.
2. What $M(\phi)$ means.
3. What $\textrm{trace}(M(\phi))$ means.

---

**Additional Details**

The book used is the course I am taking is *Abstract Linear Algebra* by Curtis, although this exercise may not be from the text itself.

---

As always, **thank you** all for your help.

Comment: From the notation we can read that $\phi$ is in the domain of $\textrm{trace}$, so it is an endomorphism of $V$. I'd venture a guess that $M(\phi)$ denotes the matrix representation of $\phi$ with respect to some basis. In order for $\mathrm{trace}$ to be well-defined, $\mathrm{trace}(M(\phi))$ must be indepdent of the choice of basis, but this turns out to be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice job framing your question precisely!

1. $\phi$ is the variable of this particular function.  Just like the $x$ in $f(x) = x^2$.  It stands for any member of $\operatorname{End}(V)$.
2. I don't think it's standard notation, but from the context I gather that $M(\phi)$ is a matrix associated to $\phi$. Once you choose a basis $v_1, v_2, \dots v_n$ for $V$, you know that there are constants $(a_{ij})$ such that 
   $$
       \phi(v_j) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} v_i
   $$
   for each $j$.  Then $M(\phi)$ is the matrix whose $(i,j)$th entry is $a_{ij}$.
3. Now you know that $M(\phi)$ is a matrix, it should be clear that $\operatorname{trace}(\phi)$ is the trace of this matrix.

Something to think about/prove: If you need to choose a basis to find $M(\phi)$, does the trace depend on that basis?  If it does, trace is not a function on endomorphisms, only on matrices.

Then you have to show that the trace satisfies the linearity properties.  But that should be straightforward.